# Crash log analysis

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, crash-reports

I have a customer who has submitted to me about ten crash logs, and I have symbolized the logs in XCode. I just have no idea what this means. Please help me analyze this crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 0E7CF1DF-B79C-4AE1-9FB3-7F13D916C844
CrashReporter Key:   0d530a5efc7ff5fff35f75efe047862f1e3ec068
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Process:         MyStocks [292]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/B120B24C-1B9A-4077-AED3-1364779DBB84/MyStocks.app/MyStocks
Identifier:      MyStocks
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-05-28 12:12:41.766 -0400
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J3)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32fa3a1c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x362063b4 pthread_kill + 52
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x361febf8 abort + 72
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x30e7da64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32dcb06c _objc_terminate + 104
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x30e7be36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x30e7be8a std::terminate() + 10
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x30e7bf5a __cxa_throw + 78
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32dc9c84 objc_exception_throw + 64
9   CoreFoundation                  0x30adc1b8 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 96
10  CoreFoundation                  0x30adb642 ___forwarding___ + 502
11  CoreFoundation                  0x30a52178 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 40
12  MyStocks                        0x0000cd28 +[YahooFinanceAPI stockIsValid:] (YahooFinanceAPI.m:31)
13  MyStocks                        0x0000bb20 -[StockText check] (StockText.m:51)
14  Foundation                      0x35e0f7c6 __NSFireTimer + 130
15  CoreFoundation                  0x30aafa40 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
16  CoreFoundation                  0x30ab1ec4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 844
17  CoreFoundation                  0x30ab283e __CFRunLoopRun + 1082
18  CoreFoundation                  0x30a42ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
19  CoreFoundation                  0x30a42dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
20  GraphicsServices                0x36188418 0x36184000 + 17432
21  GraphicsServices                0x361884c4 0x36184000 + 17604
22  UIKit                           0x30f5ed62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
23  UIKit                           0x30f5c800 UIApplicationMain + 664
24  MyStocks                        0x00002c88 main (main.m:14)
25  MyStocks                        0x00002c08 start + 44

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32fa4fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x32fcf032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x32fd003a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x32fcf5ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3620758a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36207bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32fa1c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32fa1758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30ab02b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30ab2562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30a42ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30a42dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x336c827e RunWebThread(void*) + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3620630a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36207bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32fa1c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32fa1758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30ab02b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30ab2562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30a42ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30a42dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x35da97f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x35d9c382 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x35e0e5c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3620630a _pthread_start + 242
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36207bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32fa3c60 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x30ab58f2 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3620630a _pthread_start + 242
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36207bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32fa43ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x362076d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36207bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3fb8e48c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x002e46ec      r7: 0x2fdfe7f8
    r8: 0x00245f70    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x3f646b98     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfe7ec      lr: 0x368d23bb      pc: 0x337e1a1c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0xf2fff +MyStocks armv7  <5a9bc2940092fcb19620e8be465b8847> /var/mobile/Applications/B120B24C-1B9A-4077-AED3-1364779DBB84/MyStocks.app/MyStocks
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30e06000 - 0x310f3fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x31140000 - 0x31145fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3145a000 - 0x3145bfff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x31706000 - 0x31706fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x31716000 - 0x31723fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x31724000 - 0x31725fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x31797000 - 0x317d9fff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31a71000 - 0x31a71fff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x31bae000 - 0x31c57fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x31c58000 - 0x31c63fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x31db6000 - 0x31e75fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31e76000 - 0x31e78fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x31e79000 - 0x31e96fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3219d000 - 0x321a1fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x321b0000 - 0x3220ffff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x322de000 - 0x322ecfff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32348000 - 0x3234ffff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x32350000 - 0x3295bfff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x32a50000 - 0x32a7ffff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x32c4c000 - 0x32d39fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x32d49000 - 0x32d4dfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d2f7fd2a352b3cd59c564be34b53cf80> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x32d4e000 - 0x32d53fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x32d54000 - 0x32d54fff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x32d7f000 - 0x32d82fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x32eac000 - 0x33239fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x3323a000 - 0x3323dfff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x332b5000 - 0x3339afff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x333e6000 - 0x33425fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3342f000 - 0x33431fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x33485000 - 0x33487fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x334ce000 - 0x3357ffff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x335e1000 - 0x33702fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x33771000 - 0x33771fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3377a000 - 0x337cffff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x337d0000 - 0x337e7fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <a06ec84e53bf32098b63c0caebdb45b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3392a000 - 0x3392bfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x33a3b000 - 0x33a70fff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x33a84000 - 0x33b9efff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x33cdf000 - 0x33d1bfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x33e2d000 - 0x33e9cfff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x33e9d000 - 0x33ea6fff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x33fb0000 - 0x33fbdfff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x340a5000 - 0x340d8fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x340dc000 - 0x35b2afff  TextInput armv7  <f242acc046073c1598195dd26fd8ad6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x35b2b000 - 0x35b2bfff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x35b2c000 - 0x35c4bfff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x35c61000 - 0x35c67fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x35d27000 - 0x35debfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x35dec000 - 0x35e24fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x35e25000 - 0x35f51fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <113de5f9858c32b8b158bfdc68042a97> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x35f72000 - 0x35f91fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3615c000 - 0x36168fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x36184000 - 0x36190fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <ff78a9636e933f0dbd222f8d26209788> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3654e000 - 0x36552fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x36561000 - 0x365abfff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3661a000 - 0x3662ffff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x367ef000 - 0x3689efff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x3689f000 - 0x36920fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <a7077267b6743ed3bbdd86d4380c75d9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3698b000 - 0x3698cfff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <e8858a499d663e6a9e3c188521273cc1> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x369f7000 - 0x369f8fff  TextInput_fr armv7  <df896624a716399f877087d35f6c6d86> /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_fr.bundle/TextInput_fr
0x36bfd000 - 0x36c02fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x36c09000 - 0x36c4ffff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x36cbb000 - 0x36cf3fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x36cf4000 - 0x36cf5fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x36d0d000 - 0x36da2fff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x36ded000 - 0x36df4fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36e84000 - 0x36eadfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x36efd000 - 0x37001fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x37002000 - 0x37039fff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x37058000 - 0x37071fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3716a000 - 0x3716ffff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <c7cfe523e2d73521abc01587313ef730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x371ba000 - 0x371bcfff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x37297000 - 0x372e8fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3734c000 - 0x374a0fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x374a4000 - 0x374c4fff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x374c5000 - 0x374cafff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e57c2b9054b831d9a37119baaa4947cb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x37539000 - 0x37576fff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit appears to be here:

- 64 9 CoreFoundation 0x30adc1b8 -**[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]**
- 96 10 CoreFoundation 0x30adb642 __forwarding
- 502 11 CoreFoundation 0x30a52178 _CF_forwarding_prep_0
- 40 12 MyStocks 0x0000cd28 **+[YahooFinanceAPI stockIsValid:]** (YahooFinanceAPI.m:31)

Like Jano said, possibly a missing method (if that's the case, there should be a warning somewhere).
Either that, or maybe you're accessing an invalid pointer (something you "over released"?).

Comment: Thanks, I know the method is valid, it is a core method in my app, but over releasing may be the problem. I will look into that.

Comment: Note that `YahooFinanceAPI` is a class so you are not releasing/retaining it. Maybe `stockIsValid:` is an instance method (-), and not a class method (+).

Answer (score 3):

I bet two bucks on a missing method at `YahooFinanceAPI:31 +[YahooFinanceAPI stockIsValid:]`.

Comment: No, there is no missing method.